# Computation of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field.

Consider the map $k[X,X^{-1},Y, Y^{-1}] \to k[T, T^{-1}]  $ where $X \to T$ and
$Y \to T$.

I'm interested in computing the tensor product 
$ k[T,T^{-1}] \otimes_{k[X,X^{-1},Y, Y^{-1}]} k[X^{1/n},Y^{1/n},X^{-1/n},Y^{-1/n}] $.

I'm not sure how to proceed with this computation. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the lemma $R/I \otimes_R S \cong S/IS$, and then simplify.

Capital variables are very easy to mistype, so I'll use lower case.

Let $R=k[x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}]\cong k[x,y,z,w]/(xz-1,yw-1)$, then $k[t,t^{-1}]\cong R/(x-y)$, since then $z-w = (xzw-w)-(yzw-z)$ is contained in the ideal automatically. Also $S:=k[x^{1/n},y^{1/n},x^{-1/n},y^{-1/n}]\cong R[a,b]/(a^n-x,b^n-y)$.

Thus $$k[t,t^{-1}]\otimes_R S\cong R/(x-y)\otimes_R R[a,b]/(a^n-x,b^n-y)$$
$$\cong R[a,b]/(a^n-x,b^n-y,x-y)$$
$$\cong k[x,y,z,w,a,b]/(xz-1,yw-1,a^n-x,b^n-y,x-y)$$
$$\cong k[x,z,a,b]/(xz-1,a^n-x,b^n-x)$$
$$\cong k[a,b,u]/(a^n-b^n,au-1)$$